# Node js, как удалить верхний уровень "пути"

Tags: node.js

Например есть путь:

```
const examplePath = "test/realStuff/1.png";
```

Как удалить "test", чтобы получить:

```
realStuff/1.png
```

Вариант с [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) не подходит.

Comment: И чем же не подходит вариант с replace?

Comment: Там не всегда может быть "test", как минимум нужна регулярка. Я вообще думал, что можно сделать через `path`, но у меня не получилось...

Comment: `examplePath.replace(/^[^/]+\//, '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const examplePath = "test/realStuff/1.png";

console.log(examplePath.split`/`.slice(1).join`/`);
```